# Unable to add defaults items to angular dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm trying to display some default selected data to my angular dropdown menu but for some reason if i `push()` the items from inside the `subscribe()` method the items does not being selected and if i try adding the items outside of this specific subscribe method it adds the items to the dropdown without any problems.

**NOTE:** If i log my array, it gives me all the items, including the items that i added from inside the subscribe()

**Part of my component:**

```
    public students = []
    public loadedSelectedStudents = []
    public selectedStudents = []

    // Get all selected students
    this.studentService.getStaffStudents(+loadedUserId).subscribe(async selectedStudents => {

        for (var i = 0; i < selectedStudents.length; i++) {

            var selectedStudentId: number = selectedStudents[i].studentId
            var studentModel: StaffStudentModel = new StaffStudentModel()
            studentModel.userId = +loadedUserId
            studentModel.studentId = selectedStudentId
            
            var resStudent: StudentModel = await this.studentService.getStudent(selectedStudentId).toPromise()
            
            // THIS IS NOT WORKING
            this.loadedSelectedStudents.push({ student_id: studentModel.studentId, student_name: resStudent.name })
            this.selectedStudents.push({ student_id: studentModel.studentId, student_name: resStudent.name})
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

        }

    })

    // THIS IS WORKING
    this.selectedStudents.push({student_id: 5, student_name: "Jonh"})
```

**Part of my service:**

```
getStaffStudents(userId: number) : any {
    return this.http.get<StudentModel[]>(this.baseUrl + 'Api/GetStaffStudents/' + userId).pipe(map(res => res))
}
```

**My dropdown settings and FormGroup:**

```
this.studentsDropDownSettings = {
    idField: 'student_id',
    textField: 'student_name',
    allowSearchFilter: true,
    noDataAvailablePlaceholderText: "No Available Students"
}

this.studentsDropDownForm = this.fb.group({
    studentsItems: [this.selectedStudents]
});
```

**And my HTML element:**

```
<div *ngIf="showStudensMenu" class="form-group">
    <form [formGroup]="studentsDropDownForm">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Students *</label>
        <ng-multiselect-dropdown
        [settings]="studentsDropDownSettings" 
        [data]="students"
        (onSelect)="onStudentSelected($event)"
        (onSelectAll)="onAllStudentsSelected()"
        (onDeSelect)="onStudentDeSelected($event)"
        (onDeSelectAll)="onAllStudentsDeSelected()"
        formControlName="studentsItems">
        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This happens because the html part of the component loads but the data
> hasn't come from the api yet i.e. subscription is not yet complete.

You need to set a flag, say `isLoaded` as `true` on successful subscription and update the form as well. In html, use  a `ngIf` statement so that the dropdown does not load without the data.

```html
<div *ngIf="isLoaded && showStudensMenu" class="form-group">
    <form [formGroup]="studentsDropDownForm">
        <!-- your code -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Subscription:

```js
  this.studentService.getStaffStudents(+loadedUserId).subscribe(async selectedStudents => {
        //your code
        this.isLoaded=true;
        //Update the Form
        this.studentsDropDownForm = this.fb.group({
           studentsItems: [this.selectedStudents]
        });
        }

    })
```

Don't forget to initialize isLoaded as false;

Comment: I'm getting this error when i update the form:
Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'studentsItems'

Comment: @GSepetadelis Oh this happened probably because form was built/modified dynamically after render. In html, change  formControlName="studentsItems" to "formControl]="form.controls['studentsitems']. Let me know if it works.

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: Look for studentsItems used at two places - one in subscription and one public. Try to keep form update in seperate function and call it.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

But the multiselect is consuming `[data]="students"` shouldn't you push the new items to `students[]`? If the selected values are indeed read from `this.selectedStudents` you could trigger change detection by resetting the items using spread `...` e.g `this.selectedStudents = [...this.selectedStudents]`.

Comment: i have added the students elements inside my ngOnInit()